# ASP.Net Identity Email Confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm encountering an issue with the email confirmation functionality in my ASP.NET project.

I have a functioning mail sender that generates and sends a confirmation code as expected. However, when following the generated link, only part of the generated code is returned. The code is generated using the User.Id and a code from the User object. This generates correctly and is emailed properly, but when following the link, only the User.Id value is received, and the code value returns NULL.

In the register controller, I have the following code to generate the code:

```
// ... (Previous code)
var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));

_logger.LogInformation($"UserId: {userId}, Code: {code}");
// ... (Remaining code)
```

The log shows the userId and the code, and I have cross-checked it with the code in the email. However, when the link is followed and the ConfirmEmail controller is called, the following code fails:

```
// ... (Previous code)
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"ConfirmEmail - UserId: {userId}, Code: {code}");

    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }
    // ... (Remaining code)
}
```

The first if statement fails, stating that UserId has a value but Code is NULL. I can't figure out why. I have set up the Forgot password function in the same way, and it works without any issues.

Initially, I thought it might be an issue with Brave and the "Clean Link" function, but the same problem occurs in Chrome and IE. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you're providing userId and code as parameters? Can you show your url? as an option if your params are part of url, then you can add ```[FromQuery]``` attribute to your userId and code params. Because from I can see, your url should be next: ```...?userId=***&code=***```

Comment: Here is a link that I have received during testing: Please confirm your account by <a href='https://localhost:7251/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=a555ae02-f98c-4886-b2a7-c095ca6d6a4f&amp;code=Q2ZESjhMT0R3S2VreE1ORG1rWmUvSnY3NFJyK2U5Z0J2Mk9RdlFEN3pQdTVCTGp5cmZjNVBPYi9xaU43aDlkMm5lUG1qbnFnRktDblkrVW5FWXd2UUVoSUsxdkR4QkJPVVY2NjUySjJ6UFk3ZjJ3RXpDZW5JalJ3MkVNaDBWVjVFV1VnZzZ3c0c5dTFmN2tqZUxDMGk2b29rWEhkWnVsR3J3ZnlMeEFhSzk0L1VxeXVMam9VcVpoSS9DRmZhQ1Q1ZjhBaEx0VFBnUFF0aXpMVGNicEw0NUZtN3l6cmdZTWpFNEZ5Sm9YQjRKMTdQd2VXOEltaURFb3hFTyt2VWFSTllqMS9VQT09&amp;returnUrl=%2F'>clicking here</a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on standard you would need to replace `;` delimeter to `&`.
Reference information - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

You current url:
`https://localhost:7251/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=a555ae02-f98c-4886-b2a7-c095ca6d6a4f&amp;code=Q2ZESjhMT0R3S2VreE1ORG1rWmUvSnY3NFJyK2U5Z0J2Mk9RdlFEN3pQdTVCTGp5cmZjNVBPYi9xaU43aDlkMm5lUG1qbnFnRktDblkrVW5FWXd2UUVoSUsxdkR4QkJPVVY2NjUySjJ6UFk3ZjJ3RXpDZW5JalJ3MkVNaDBWVjVFV1VnZzZ3c0c5dTFmN2tqZUxDMGk2b29rWEhkWnVsR3J3ZnlMeEFhSzk0L1VxeXVMam9VcVpoSS9DRmZhQ1Q1ZjhBaEx0VFBnUFF0aXpMVGNicEw0NUZtN3l6cmdZTWpFNEZ5Sm9YQjRKMTdQd2VXOEltaURFb3hFTyt2VWFSTllqMS9VQT09&amp;returnUrl=%2F%27%3Eclicking`

Where you do `?userId=***;code=***`, but you need to have `?userId=***&code=***`. Simply try to replace your delimeter in your browser, it should feed proper information to your controller.

Comment: Dude you are a rock star, this worked perfectly thank you, I have been trying to trouble shoot this for days now

Comment: so I am a noob with this and I fixed it by moving the HTML encode out od the email sender function and then relacing the semicolon, not the most eligant but it works```callbackUrl = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);
// Replace the delimiter from ; to &
callbackUrl = callbackUrl.Replace(';', '&');


await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{callbackUrl}'>clicking here</a>.");```

Comment: as an option, or you can find your ```code=```, thev verify what type of character stays upfront, and if it's ```;```, then do replacement....do the root of the problem still hides inside

Comment: Actually it's the `&amp;` that sould be replaced with `&`. It seems the method produces an html-encoded url, so when you put it in a plaintext email, you can html-decode this value

Comment: @Pieterjan because html thinks that it's an ampersand? Then it means that he need to wrap the url into ```href="javascript:window.open('url.here')"```

Comment: I will give this a try as I'm having a hard time getting the href to format correctly as well, and just applied a workaround for now. But yeah the new code after replacing makes it ```&amp&``` instead of ```&amp;```

Comment: Correction, I had fix it to replace the &amp; with a &, although the email is still sending a link instead of a hyperlink on "Click here". Issue that I will look into on another day

Answer (score 0):

-> you can use UserManger.cs and EmailService.cs file to handle email confirmation.

-> I provide sample code to help you.

-> In this code, Register action in AccountController for registering new user.then after it generates email confirmation token and send email with this URL to user.ConfirmEmail action in controller , confirms the User's email ddress when click on the link and sent to the their email.

->Please check , email service in your Appliction use such as SMTP or external email service provide like SendGrid. and set up the necessary views (Register.cshtml, RegistrationConfirmation.cshtml, ConfirmEmail.cshtml) for this functionality.

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                return View("RegistrationConfirmation");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
    }

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }
}

public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try as well, as I need to clean up the code a bit, but focused on having all aspects working for now... Its the first time I work with C# so neaten and optimize later